# NSKeyedArchiver returning nil Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, persistence, nskeyedarchiver, nscoder

```
 let lessons = Lessons(definition: "testo", photo: url)
 SaveUtil.saveLessons(lessons: lessons!)
 let x = SaveUtil.loadLessons()
```

So everything compiles and runs but x is nil....I'm trying to make this ios12/swift 4.2 compliant but no idea what is missing. Thank you!

```
class SaveUtil {
    static func saveLessons(lessons: Lessons) {
        let data = try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: lessons, requiringSecureCoding: false)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "lessons")
    }

    static func loadLessons() -> [Lessons]?  {

        let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "lessons")
        return try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data!) as? [Lessons]
    }
}
```

Comment: That's bcause you are not specifying the class name.

Comment: @ElTomato can you please elaborate?

Comment: The type of archived root object is `Lessons`, not `[Lessons]`.

Comment: @OOPer YEP!! xcode autofix did that....and im such noob to swift that it flew right by me. Please submit an answer for easy points!! ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the loadSession returns a array of Lesson. "as?" will check for type. As the unarchived object was not a array it will return nil. You are archiving it as Lesson Object and unarchiving it as Lesson Array Object.

```
static func loadLessons() -> Lessons?  {

        let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "lessons")

        return try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data!) as? Lessons
    }
```

Below is the code that works .

```
class Lessons : NSObject,NSCoding {

    var definitionText:String
    var photoURL:String

    init(definition:String,photoURL:String) {
        self.definitionText = definition
        self.photoURL = photoURL
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(self.definitionText, forKey: "definitionText")
        aCoder.encode(self.photoURL, forKey: "photoURL")
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init(definition: "", photoURL: "")
        self.definitionText = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "definitionText") as! String
        self.photoURL = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "photoURL") as! String
    }
}
class SaveUtil {
    static func saveLessons(lessons: Lessons) {

        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: lessons)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "lessons")
    }

    static func loadLessons() -> Lessons?  {
        let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "lessons")
        return try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data!) as? Lessons
    }
}
```

After which you run your code it will return the object.

```
let lessons = Lessons(definition: "testo", photoURL: "photo.jpg")
        SaveUtil.saveLessons(lessons: lessons)
        let x = SaveUtil.loadLessons()
        print("\(x?.photoURL)")
```